# XML, Namespaces, E4X

Tags: xml, namespaces, e4x

I have this XML file:

```
var k= <texta xmlns="http://www.ert.com" xmlns:ns="http://asd/asi/" xmlns:xsd="http://dgewdged" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://sasdfasdf" xmlns:xsi="http://asdfasdgsde">
  <textb>
    <textc>Test</textc>
  </textb>
</texta>
```

how can i get with E4X only the text "Test"?

```
var text=k.textb;
Alert(text);
```

I tried it on this way...but i get:

```
<textb xmlns="http://www.ert.com" xmlns:ns="http://asd/asi/" xmlns:xsd="http://dgewdged" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://sasdfasdf" xmlns:xsi="http://asdfasdgsde">
    <textc>Test</textc>
  </textb>
```

How can i remove the whole Namespaces ?

thank you for your help.

Comment: E4X has been deprecated since 2014. I don't think I even have any software capable of running it these days. I'd strongly suggest switching to something else to process your XML.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to access those elements.

### Setting the default namespace

```
default xml namespace = 'http://www.ert.com';
var text = k.textb.textc.toString();
Alert(text);
// reset to empty namespace
default xml namespace = '';
```

### Using an explicit namespace

```
var ert = new Namespace('http://www.ert.com');
var text = k.ert::textb.ert::textc.toString();
Alert(text);
```

### Using namespace wildcards

```
var text = k.*::textb.*::textc.toString();
Alert(text);
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was the solution to your issue.